# Странности загрузки исходного кода

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, webbrowser

Когда заходите на [сайт](http://tankist10.hosting-test.org.ua/) происходит загрузка странички, когда все загружено остальная часть страницы загружается через ajax

```
xml.onload = function(){
   if(xml.readyState===4&&xml.status===200){
      $('article').html(xml.responseText);
   }
}
```

Если посмотреть после этого в исходный код(нажать именно "Исходный код страницы", а не "Исходный код элемента"), то там есть только та часть которая загружалась через ajax.
А из-за этого есть проблемы, например если с этого сайта перейти на любой другой, а потом нажать кнопочку назад то можно увидеть только тот кусок страницы который загружен был через ajax.
Как исправить это?

Comment: вот вы даете - реализуете ajax запрос руками, когда есть $.ajax() в jquery....

что-то у всех одинаковые проблемы - отличайте на стороне сервера ajax и не ajax загрузку, если ajax, то возвращайте только часть, а если не ajax, то возвращайте всё и заголовки и футеры.

Comment: извините, но я ничего не понял

Comment: Во первых:

    Uncaught ReferenceError: setting is not defined  ajax.js:131
    xml.onload

во вторых, попробуйте сделать чтобы url в ajax запросе не совпадал с url страницы, хром как-то странно глючит по этому поводу.

Comment: [говорят баг в chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8568402/815386) странно что уже год как не пофикшено...

Comment: Странно у меня нет той ошибки что у Вас и это не только в хроме, но и в других браузерах(на счет исходного кода, а не кнопки назад). А за ссылку Спасибо!